# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'Variable' Tensorflow MNIST

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, mnist

I am following a tutorial in TensorFlow and MNIST. I do not understand the error message or how to fix it. I am using Jupyter Notebook, Python 2.7. Is this a python version issue and if so how can I fix this?

The code and error follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# Model! 
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), W), + b)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-00f12701ef74> in <module>()
      1 # Model!
----> 2 

Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), W), + b)
```

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'Variable'

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), **W), + b)
```

**should be**

```
Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X, [-1, 784]), **W) + b)
```

Comment: Both things are exactly the same'